# Connecting dropdown picker to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, xamarin, computer-science

I am working on a project where I gotta create a signup page and in that page I have to have a dropdown picker so that user can choose the country of where they are from. I am following some of the steps in this video I found on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_0XDyy4ef8 and a course on udemy but they do not go into the steps on how to create the backend code to connect it to the database. If someone could help me out that be great!

xaml-

```
<Picker ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CountryName}" 
                        x:Name="EntCountry" 
                        Title="Select Country" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding CountList}" 
                        TextColor="White" 
                        TitleColor="White"/>
```

cs-

```
 private async void BtnSignUp_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var response = await ApiService.RegisterUser(EntName.Text, EntEmail.Text, EntPassword.Text, EntConfirmPassword.Text, EntDOB.Text, EntCountry);
                if (response)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Hello!", "Your account has been created", "Okay");
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage()); //This will transition to another screen. 
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Hello!", "There is something wrong", "Okay");
            }
        }
```

Register.cs

```
class Register
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string DOB { get; set; }
    }
```

ApiService.cs-

```
public static async Task<bool> RegisterUser(string name, string email, string password, string confirmpassword, string dob, string country)
        {
            var register = new Register()
            {
                Name = name,
                Email = email,
                Password = password,
                ConfirmPassword = confirmpassword,
                Country = country,
                DOB = dob,
```

Country.cs-

```
public class Country
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }
```

CountryViewModel.cs-

```
class CountryViewModel
    {
        public IList<Country> CountList { get; set; }

        public CountryViewModel()
        {
            try
            {
                CountList = new ObservableCollection<Country>();
                CountList.Add(new Country { CountryId = 1, CountryName = "United States" });
                CountList.Add(new Country { CountryId = 2, CountryName = "Ecuador" });
                CountList.Add(new Country { CountryId = 3, CountryName = "Brazil" });
                CountList.Add(new Country { CountryId = 4, CountryName = "Argentina" });
                CountList.Add(new Country { CountryId = 5, CountryName = "Colombia" });
                CountList.Add(new Country { CountryId = 6, CountryName = "Peru" });
                CountList.Add(new Country { CountryId = 7, CountryName = "Chile" });
                CountList.Add(new Country { CountryId = 8, CountryName = "Venezuela" });
                CountList.Add(new Country { CountryId = 9, CountryName = "Bolivia" });
                CountList.Add(new Country { CountryId = 10, CountryName = "Uruguay" });
                CountList.Add(new Country { CountryId = 11, CountryName = "Paraguay" });
                CountList.Add(new Country { CountryId = 12, CountryName = "Mexico" });
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then perhaps you need another video on how to query a database from c# - it's a bit broad for an SO question

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the BindingContext for the VM? Take a look at [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/154266/picker-mvvm-two-picker-has-data-relative-using-binding). As a recommendation, if you use VM try to put the code of the click button inside it.